# how to get correct answer merge 2 sorted arrays?! C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, merge

i wrote a little algorithm for marge to sorted array. but i have problem with that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    // main function started form here:

    int firstArray[10] = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19};
    int secondtArray[10] = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};

    int mergedArray[20];
    int firstCounter=0 , secondtCounter=0 , mergedCounter=0;

    while(firstCounter < 10 && secondtCounter < 10){
        if(firstArray[firstCounter] < secondtArray[secondtCounter]){
            mergedArray[mergedCounter] = firstArray[firstCounter];
            firstCounter++;
        } else {
            mergedArray[mergedCounter] = secondtArray[secondtCounter];
            secondtCounter++;
        }
        mergedCounter++;
    }

    while(firstCounter < 10) {
        mergedArray[mergedCounter] = firstArray[firstCounter];
        firstCounter++;
        mergedCounter++;
    }

    while(secondtCounter < 10) {
        mergedArray[mergedCounter];
        secondtCounter++;
        mergedCounter++;
    }

    for(int j=0; j<20; j++){
        //cout << mergedArray[j] << endl;
    }
    cout << mergedArray[19];

    return 0;
}
```

in outpout for array `mergedArray[19]` i get something like this: `2686916`!!!

i don't know why i get this value. how can i fix that. and why i get this value.

Comment: This : `mergedArray[mergedCounter];` as a single statement in your final consolidation loop isn't going to do much. You forgot the assignment part. And heeding your compiler warning that says "code has no effect" would have told you this. Compile with a high-warning level and don't ignore them when they pop up.

Comment: You compiler might have issued a warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo in last while. You may increase your warning level to let your compiler show you your typo (`warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]`).

```
while(secondtCounter < 10) {
    mergedArray[mergedCounter];
    secondtCounter++;
    mergedCounter++;
}
```

should be

```
while(secondtCounter < 10) {
    mergedArray[mergedCounter] = secondtArray[secondtCounter];
    secondtCounter++;
    mergedCounter++;
}
```

Comment: yeah .. TnX so much... i fixed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by WhozCraig's comment, you're not assigning any value to `mergedArray[19]` because you left out the assignment part of the statement.

Since you haven't assigned a value, it's printing out whatever value happens to be at that memory address from previous usage.  If you run your program (as it's currently written) several times, you'll see that the number there might change.  Also, if you'd printed out the values in mergedArray before assigning anything, you'd see more such meaningless (to you in the current application) numbers.